# My Existing TableViewController is crashing on Xcode 11 beta1

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, xcode11, ios13

I have developed a `UITableViewController` screen. It's working fine on **Xcode 10.2** but. When I run on **Xcode 11 beta 1** it's crashing like below.

I didn't find what was happening.

*In ViewDidLoad*

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    plateNoPrefix.becomeFirstResponder() // static cell textfield in tableViewcell
}
```

> Exception… Attempted to access the table view's visibleCells while they were in the process of being updated, which is not allowed

Comment: As of xcode 11 beta 4, it will throw a warning instead of crashing.

Comment: For me it happen when setting `UITextView.text = "text"`, after few betas it has been fixed/stoped crashing on that line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have faced the same issue when providing support for iOS 13.

> This is a new exception in iOS 13 that `UITableView` will raise in order
> to prevent and proactively alert you of a situation that would
> previously cause undefined behaviour and a variety of strange,
> seemingly unrelated, and hard-to-debug issues (including crashes).
>
> What is happening here is that `UITableView` is in the middle of asking
> its dataSource to return a cell for each `visible row` and is
> configuring the properties of the returned cells so they can be
> displayed. And in the middle of this updating -- most likely inside a
> callback from the table view itself about a specific row such as
> `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:) tableView(_:canEditRowAt:)`, etc -- your
> code is asking the table view to return the visible cells. This is
> obviously problematic, because `UITableView` is right in the middle of
> preparing those cells, so it cannot possibly return a meaningful
> answer.
>
> The fix for this is to look at where you are calling `visibleCells` in
> the backtrace when this `exception` is raised, and then do one of two
> things:

**Option 1:**

> Move the usage of `visibleCells` to a better place, so that you aren't
> asking for the `visibleCells` from someplace that is called during the
> process of creating/configuring/updating those same cells. A great
> place to ask for the visible cells is after the table view lays out,
> so for example if the table view is the view of a view controller you
> can use `viewDidLayoutSubviews`(), or in a subclass of `UITableView` do it
> after calling `super.layoutSubviews()`.

**Option 2:**

> Depending on what you're actually trying to do, you might be able to
> skip using visible cells altogether. For example, you might be able to
> leverage the callbacks `tableView(_:willDisplay:forRowAt:)` and
> `tableView(_:didEndDisplaying:forRowAt:)` to track when cells are
> visible instead.
>
> If you are hitting this exception and you think you are requesting the
> visible cells from a location that should be valid/allowed, please
> share the backtrace when you hit this exception and details about what
> you're trying to do.

**Update:**

I am sure but `plateNoPrefix.becomeFirstResponder()` causing the crash. As of now, you can check by pasting this code in `viewDidAppear` method

**OR**

Execute this code after delay **(Worked for me)**

```
 DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+0.1) {
      // Your code
 }
```

For details clerification you can refer [Apple Developer Forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/117537)

Comment: I get Assert's not crashes: [Assert] Attempted to call -cellForRowAtIndexPath: on the table view while it was in the process of updating its visible cells, which is not allowed. Make a symbolic breakpoint at UITableViewAlertForCellForRowAtIndexPathAccessDuringUpdate

Answer (score 3):

**This is a new exception in iOS 13 that UITableView will raise in order to prevent and proactively alert you of a situation that would previously cause undefined behavior and a variety of strange, seemingly unrelated, and hard-to-debug issues**

Please have a look at [Apple Developer Forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/117537)

Comment: Have the same issue on Beta7. Will update here once find a solution